# Alert Meassage Box apper Issue in sencha

Tags: sencha-touch-2, alerts

I am working on Sencha touch app.in this app a error message repeatedly occurs . but i was not put any such type alert in app.how can i prevent this thing.Please anybody can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: may be version problem , means check the api

Comment: You could try to search the source for `Ext.msg` alerts.